# MS SQL Server subquery returning more than one value(string)

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am having problem concatenating the result of a subquery which is giving String results.

Actually my subquery has a CASE WHEN statement and list function doesn't work in MS SQL server. So I need to somehow concatenate the result of this subquery so that the result is visible in a single row.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
select 
.......,(select CASE WHEN pm.PaymentType = 1 THEN   'Cash'      
                     WHEN pm.PaymentType = 2 THEN   'Check'       
                     WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 THEN   'Credit Card'   
                     ELSE   'Money Order'   
                END
          from 
             <some tables with all the joins> 
          where 
             <all the conditions>) AS [PAYMENT TYPE],
....... 
from 
<some more tables with joins> 
where 
<some other conditions>
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Does SQL Server support the group_concat function?

Comment: What joins are linking the sub query to the main query?

Comment: Some LEFT joins with INNER joins, actually where clause is the one that joins subquery to main query, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the 3 ways I know (and probably easiest for you) is xml-trick:

```
select 
.......,
     stuff(
          (
           select
               ',' + 
               CASE
                   WHEN pm.PaymentType = 1 THEN 'Cash'      
                   WHEN pm.PaymentType = 2 THEN 'Check'       
                   WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 THEN 'Credit Card'   
                   ELSE 'Money Order'   
               END
           from <some tables with all the joins> 
           where <all the conditions>
           for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'') AS [PAYMENT TYPE]
....... 
from 
<some more tables with joins> 
where 
<some other conditions>
```

Comment: Actually I am running a .dqy file for importing all the data in excel sheet directly. I dont think XML will work in this type of file.

Comment: I tried the above the code and it worked..... Thanks, should have tried it earlier.